# Symfony 2 - FOSCommentBundle : add attachment feature

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to add functionality to attach a file to a comment. The upload of the image would automatically when the user drops the file into the form (in the same way that you attach a file with gmail). My question is how do I do to find the file that was previously sent to the server when the comment is submitted and to delete the comment if the document is never submitted.

Do any of you have already done something similar?

Here's the association I have between my classes Comment  and Document.

```
class Comment extends BaseComment
{
    /** ...  */

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Document", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="fls_comment_and_documents",
     * joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="comment_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="document_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     * )
     * 
     * @var ArrayCollection $documents
     */
    protected $documents;

     /** ...  */ 
}
```

Thanks in advance !